# How to ensure that my left div element does not change the position of my right div element, when left div element gets long?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I have two div elements that are positioned side by side. The left side div is an action link , and the right side div is an icon. The issue I am having is that, when I type a lengthy name for the action link title (example: "ActionLinkTitleNameVeryLongTitleABCDE"), it moves the position of my right side div icon - to the right. I am looking for a way where no matter how long the action link title is, the right side div icon should not move from it's original position. Even if the title is really long, it should be displayed on top of the icon(overlap), but the position of icon shouldn't change. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/f5c1xrq3/17/  `.`

```css
.content {

        .bottomLeft 
        {
            height: 36px;
            color: blue;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .bottomRight {
            height: 77px;
        }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomLeft">
<a href=@_Functions.GetUrlValueBySchema(link) title=@link.LinkName>@linkTitle</a>
</div> 

<div class="bottomRight">
<i class="fa-external-link pull-right" title="icon for link"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your link. Please check it if any changes than let me know.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbnz9qaj/

```css
.col_wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottomLeft {
  height: 36px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80%;
  word-break: break-all;

}

.bottomRight {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col_wrap">


  <div class="bottomLeft">
    <a href=@_Functions.GetUrlValueBySchema(link) title=@link.LinkName>ActionLinkTitleNameVeryLongTitleABCDEActionLinkTitleNameVeryLongTitleABCDEActionLinkTitleNameVeryLongTitleABCDE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="bottomRight">
    <i class="fa fa-external-link pull-right" title="icon for link"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @RevtiShah, please correct me if I am wrong but, I have tried your changes but running into few issues. If I made the action link title long, it is also extending the position of the icon as well. Meaning, as the title length increases the icon  moves it's position to the right as well. I am hoping the Icon would stay at the same place even if the title is long. Also, is it possible to have just 10px padding between the action link and the icon?

Comment: Okay i got it . i will give width to div. i will modify it and revert to you.

Comment: Hey, you have to use flex concept also.I have modified your code. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you, I have understood the use of flex now, it's working well.

Comment: Hi @Revti, just wondering if you know how to truncate text, if the text is more than 3 lines? I am seeing if there is way to do this using pure CSS only. One way to do this would be to use the  `-webkit-line-clamp = 3`, but this isn't supported on all browsers. Here is fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/h80robcu/11/. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @peter yeah i am trying to work on it. If i will solve, i will let you know.

Comment: sure. It doesn’t seem straight forward with CSS. anyhow thanks for trying.